# node.js telegram bot управление мышкой/клавой

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

Я слышал, что при помощи node.js можно научить бота управлять курсором, но не могу найти как это реализовать. Можно ли научить бота делать двойной клик или одинарный клик в определенном месте, что бы напривер открывать видео в ютуб на весь экран или паузить его? Возможно ли через бота реализовать нажатие горячих клавиш?

Comment: Учитывая все ваши вопросы которые вы тут задавали. а я отвечал... Вы уверены что вы хотите использовать node.js для этих целей? Не проще будет сделать бота на c# ?!

Comment: Возможно, но для дипломной работы я должен писать на js

Answer (score 3):

Для управления клавиатурой и мышкой в node.js можно использовать данный пакет :
[robotjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs)

Вот пример работы с клавиатурой:

```js
// Type "Hello World" then press enter.
var robot = require("robotjs");
 
// Type "Hello World".
robot.typeString("Hello World");
 
// Press enter.
robot.keyTap("enter");
```

по поводу функциональных клавиш то всю информацию можно найти [тут](http://robotjs.io/docs/syntax)